# Access Handlebars Objectvars via var

Tags: handlebars.js

Is there something like `{{foo.*index*.title}}` to access `{{foo.4.title}}` in handlebars?

```
var foo = {
   1: { title: 'foo a' },
   4: { title: 'foo b' }
   7: { title: 'foo c' }
}

var index = 4
```

Comment: I think your best bet would be to grab `foo[index]` before the data gets into the template. Otherwise you'd have to set up a custom helper to do things like `{{at foo index "title"}}`.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I take this way.